# Ansatz Techniques to Multi-Body Physics Problems

Tags: quantum-algorithms, circuit-construction, hamiltonian-simulation

I have been reading this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.01563v1.

I am wondering: is it possible to use the idea behind quantum circuits to build classical Hamiltonians represented in the same way?